# windows 7 terminal server

Tags: windows-7, domain, terminal

I reguarly use a 'mstc' Terminal server on windows 7 and logging in is fine, but everytime i logoff and go to log back on it will not save the domain and i have to keep changing it back to what it should be.

Does anybody know how to save the domain so i dont have to keep changing it?

I have tried searching the web for various websites and search engines but have had no joy as of yet! Help please!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it is not saving the user-account either ?

This is probably set as a domain policy or as a policy on the remote server as a security measure. (Not that is gains very much...)

Little you can do about that except asking the system admin to relax the restriction.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Domain Group Policies, if you have access to it (gpedit.msc) run this command from Start=>run.

Then navigate to 
User Configuration
=>Administrative Templates
=>Windows Components
    =>Remote Desktop Services
    =>Remote Desktop Connection Client

Under this node, there is an entry named "Do not allow passwords to be saved"  Makes sure that this entry is either set to Disabled or Not configured.  If it is set to Enabled, it will not allow you to save your passwords.

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is install the Windows 7 RSAT toolset. Then open up a new mmc console, add the remote desktops snapin. then configure new remote desktop connections and save the credentials through there.